# Ubuntu 20.4.1 - vscode freezing and stop responding

Tags: dual-boot, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I started studying programming this year and always did everything on windows,
but after some problems using docker I decided to do a dualboot with ubuntu.
The problem is that when I'm using vscode and need to open more than two google chrome tabs,
vscode freezes and a message appears that it has stopped responding.
The problem remains for about 5 seconds until it works again.

That is my first time with Ubuntu and Linux in general. And I would like to keep using it.

I would be very grateful if anyone has any idea why this is happening

Other details:

I downloaded vscode from the ubuntu store and I'm using the same extensions I used on windows and even when I disable them, the result is the same.

If I am using only chrome and open several tabs it will also stop responding.

I checked if swap was enabled, but it didn't seem to be the case (Maybe I just don't know how to check it properly)

About the computer:
gtx 1060 ti -
i5 7400 -
16gb ram -
HD 1.5 tb for windows and 350gb for Ubuntu

On windows this never happened, my computer can keep an android emulator running next to vscode and more than 20 chrome tabs (I tested this today, to see if the dualboot would have caused any problems).

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Check disc space, RAM usage, and CPU usage using the pre-installed `System Monitor` graphical program.

Comment: `--disable-gpu` solved it for me (U 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a driver issue. You can install the recommended drivers using:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```